# cron ++ for Windows

Tags: windows, scheduler

I would like to setup job scheduling on my Windows 7 machine that kicks of jobs and create alarms when they fail. Ideally so that I can run jobs on remote agents.

Autosys, visualcron, powershell?

Lars

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the built in Task Scheduler in Windows? That seems like it meets your needs.

Comment: That's exactly what it's for.  Both 'at' and 'schtasks' provide command-line interfaces.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738335(WS.10).aspx